# HTML elements for timeline posts

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In an web application, i am displaying posts from other users in an individual user's homepage. Each post will contain the thumbnail profile picture of the person the post is from, their name on a paragraph, text contents and then a reply box and button. I am trying to do this by bootstrap's grid system but not achieving the desired effect. I want to mimic the tweets in twitter home page, but in my case there is a big gap in between the profile picture and the other column.

```
<div class="container" >
    <ul id="newsfeed">
        <li>

            <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <img src="someimage.png" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Some Image" width="60" height="60">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <p>9gag@9gag</p>
                        <p>This is me</p>
                        <p>twitted at 12:30pm GMT6+</p>
                    </div>
            </div>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap adds padding to the columns. Create a CSS class to remove the padding from your cols: `.no-padding{padding:0;}` , and then add that class to your divs; `<div class="col-sm-4 no-padding">`

Comment: thans for the reply, but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.col-sm-2` is wider than your thumbnail image you can do two things.

1) You can can use `.col-sm-1` for the image container.

```
<div class="container" >
    <ul id="newsfeed">
        <li>

            <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-sm-1 narrow">
                        <img src="someimage.png" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Some Image" width="60" height="60">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 narrow">
                        <p>9gag@9gag</p>
                        <p>This is me</p>
                        <p>twitted at 12:30pm GMT6+</p>
                    </div>
            </div>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

2) You can leave it as is but add bootstraps helper class `pull-right` to your img tag.

```
<div class="container" >
    <ul id="newsfeed">
        <li>

            <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <img src="someimage.png" class="img-thumbnail pull-right" alt="Some Image" width="60" height="60">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 narrow">
                        <p>9gag@9gag</p>
                        <p>This is me</p>
                        <p>twitted at 12:30pm GMT6+</p>
                    </div>
            </div>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/avQOEO)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Media Object](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media) component for this (and possibly without any additional CSS as far as structure is concerned).

See working example Snippet.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Posts</h1>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="media">
        <div class="media-left">
          <a href="#">
            <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/75x75/000/fff" alt="...">
          </a>

        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
          <p>tweet@tweet</p>
          <p>Some Tweet</p>
          <p>twetted at 12:30pm GMT6+</p>
        </div>
        <form>
          <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Reply..."> <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Reply</button>
      </span>

          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="media">
        <div class="media-body">
          <p>tweet@tweet</p>
          <p>Some Tweet</p>
          <p>twetted at 12:30pm GMT6+</p>
        </div>
        <div class="media-right">
          <a href="#">
            <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/75x75/f00/fff" alt="...">
          </a>

        </div>
        <form>
          <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Reply..."> <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Reply</button>
      </span>

          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="media">
        <div class="media-left">
          <a href="#">
            <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/75x75/ff0/fff" alt="...">
          </a>

        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
          <p>tweet@tweet</p>
          <p>Some Tweet</p>
          <p>twetted at 12:30pm GMT6+</p>
        </div>
        <form>
          <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Reply..."> <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Reply</button>
      </span>

          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```